# How to remove alternating whitespaces from file content

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I am grepping on a file which occasionally has words that have alternating whitespaces in them.

For instance:
`h e l l o this is an e x a m p l e`

I would like this to become:
`hello this is an example`

I am open for any command line tools to solve this problem. I would take the risk of single character words getting squashed (since they occur very seldomly in my files).

E. g.: `h e l l o this is a r i s k I would take.` becoming `hello this is ariskI would take.`

What I tried so far is this, but I guess I need some sort of look ahead:

`sed "s/\([[:alnum:]]\) \([[:alnum:]]\)/\1\2/g" mytextfile.txt`

This only gives me:
`he ll othisisane xa mp le`

I only found topics on how to trim strings or remove all blank space within a string.

Comment: `h e l l o this is an e x a m p le` is going to be next to impossible unless you lower your expectations to `hello this is an examp le`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Thanks for pointing that out, John corrected that typo for me in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work:

```regex
(?:(?<=^)|(?<= ))([^ ]) (?=[^ ] )
```

https://regex101.com/r/yLccGg/1

Comment: There is no mandatory POSIX command-line tool that would understand that regexp the way you probably intend.

Answer (score 0):

An example using node.js:

```sh
$ node -e "fs=require('fs'),fn='input.txt';fs.writeFileSync(fn,fs.readFileSync(fn,{encoding:'utf8'}).replace(/(?<=\b[a-z]) (?![A-Z]|\w\w\w)/g, ''));"
```

A space is replaced if it follows a lower-case letter and is not followed by a capital letter or three consecutive word characters.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk for patsplit() and gensub():

```
awk '{
    numFlds = patsplit($0,flds,/\<([^ ] )+[^ ]\>/,seps)
    out = seps[0]
    for ( i=1; i<=numFlds; i++ ) {
        out = out gensub(/([^ ]) /,"\\1","g",flds[i]) seps[i]
    }
    print out
}' file
hello this is an examp le
```

alternatively, still using GNU awk but now for the 3rd arg to match() and gensub():

```
$ awk '{
    while ( match($0,/\<(([^ ] )+[^ ]\>)(.*)/,a) ) {
        $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) gensub(/([^ ]) /,"\\1","g",a[1]) a[3]
    }
    print
}' file
hello this is an examp le
```

You'd have to provide an algorithm explaining why `le` should be joined to the end of `examp` for that to happen.

Comment: I think you're missing a `)` for `gensub`.

Comment: sorry, my bad...

Answer (score 0):

I inserted a space before the last `e` of your `e x a m p le`.
First you want to know the complete words.

```
echo "h e l l o this is an e x a m p l e"| sed -r 's/\w\w+/=&=/g'
```

result

```
h e l l o =this= =is= =an= e x a m p l e
```

Now all the isoloted characters can be removed in loop.

```
echo "h e l l o this is an e x a m p l e"| 
  sed -r 's/\w\w+/=&=/g;:a;s/( )([^ ])( |$)/\2\3/;ta'
```

result

```
hello =this= =is= =an=example
```

Next replace the equal signs with spaces and remove double spaces

```
echo "h e l l o this is an e x a m p l e"| 
  sed -r 's/\w\w+/=&=/g;:a;s/( )([^ ])( |$)/\2\3/;ta;s/=/ /g;s/[ ][ ]+/ /g'
```

The equal sign can be part of your string. When you use `\r` the intermediate results  don't show the clear output strings, but will be better for text without `\r`. And when you think that an isolated `I` should be considered as a work, the solution is

```
echo "h e l l o this is an e x a m p l e that I l i k e"|
  sed -r 's/( I |\w\w+)/\r&\r/g;:a;s/( )([^ ])( |$)/\2\3/;ta; s/\r/ /g;s/[ ][ ]+/ /g'
```

Result:

```
hello this is an example that I like
```

Using `awk` can be easier:

```
echo "h e l l o this is an e x a m p l e that I l i k e"|
  awk '
    BEGIN { RS="[ \n]"; FS="" }
    NF==1 { printf("%s",$0); sep=" " }
    $0=="I" { printf(" ")}
    NF>1 { printf("%s%s ", sep, $0); sep =""}
    END {print ""}
  '
```

All "words" are moved to different lines, and when the linelength becomes 1 you don't want a space. Special rules for an isolated `I`. The `sep` is used for avoiding two spaces between two more-letter words like `this is`.
Result:

```
hello this is an example that I like
```